# How to allow others to have access to my local gitlab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, gitlab

I am new to Linux and command line, so sorry if my question is way too rookie for this community but i installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtual Box and configured git lab (CE) on it. I configured also my external_URL. The git lab runs perfectly on my local network but i want to allow my friend to join me on my repository from his network. I am not sure how to put it on public IP to put it online if i have to.

Answer (score 0):

One could get a domain, and (self-hosted) dns provider and then point that domain to "your ip" and expose the GitLab ports on your device (and router). Then, if people visit your domain/website, the DNS provider points you to your pc, and if they visit the correct port, like [www.yourwebsite.com:8080](http://www.yourwebsite.com:8080) they should see your GitLab server. I am not quite sure how you should publish the website of GitLab that is available on localhost of your VirtualBox to the localhost of your PC though. I think that is the essence of your question.

An, in my eyes simpler approach, is to compute/generate a tor domain (`.onion`) for free, inside your VirtualBox and make tor forward your GitLab ports. You can do that on a Raspberry PI, from any place in the world that has internet. People can access your GitLab server from anywhere in the world and clone/push pull using torsocks.